# How to build a Filter screen in a VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to build a VF page which allows selection of Accounts. In this page i want to build a filter screen similar to a filter screen on list view edit screen.
I am short of ideas on handling the operator based on the datatypes and also getting the picklist values if the user chooses a field which is a picklist.

Any thoughts on how to approach this would be of great help. i am not in a need of the apex code but a psuedo code would be enough.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

> *O, that way madness lies* --Shakespeare

This innocent-looking UI is actually incredibly hard to get "just right." It will require hundreds, if not thousands, of lines of code, depending on how much you want to lean on internal libraries (which you *should* avoid). You'll have to figure how to describe all fields for an object, then figure out how to get their data types, then which operators are legal for which data types in SOQL, handle a few special exceptions like polymorphic fields, build some lookup widgets that can handle either picklist values, record types, or other arbitrary tables, etc. Then, after you get all of that straight, you'll have to figure how how to validate that a query is built acceptably without injection vulnerabilities.

A *very* rough outline would look like this:

```
Describe all fields for the object
Render field drop down
On field drop down change
    Describe field
    Determine operators to show
    Determine if lookup should render
    Render operator drop drown and lookup
End
On lookup popup
    If type is ID
        Show lookup window that can SOSL/SOQL records of that type
    Else
        Show available picklist values
    End if
End
On add filter logic
    Show filter input area
End
On search
    Validate filter input is valid
    Build SOQL using input criteria
    Parse and render results
End
```

Unless you're using internal libraries, you'll also need a couple of extra Visualforce pages for rendering selection elements if you want to keep that "classic" look, or you might go with something like jQuery's auto-complete module, which you can hook into some remote action functions without too much effort.

Bonus points if you use the recently viewed API in your lookup windows, and more if you actually write this module to be Salesforce1 compatible as well. I've also linked some resources you'll want to have handy.

- [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm)
- [Field Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm)
- [SOQL Limits on Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm)
- [Comparison Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)
- [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) (if you want to support date filters like the native UI)
- [Querying Currency Fields in Multicurrency Organizations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm) (if you need multi-currency support)

You'll probably find additional resources useful as well, but this should cover the basics.

I'm leaving this answer as a Community Wiki. I would encourage additional edits to this answer that people find useful.